# Multiple problems when building apk in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, build, android-asynctask

This may be a duplicate, but I and some others have been unable to find a solution to this build problem with [our app.](https://github.com/filcnaplo/filcnaplo)

For a while now we were getting notes and warnings on deprecated libraries, but it seems like this new problem is now completely preventing the build (full output below):

```
major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
```

An important caveat is that `flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64` works fine, just showing the deprecated notes.

What should I do to fix the apk build; how do I update the compiler as mentioned above, if that turns out to be the problem? How do I update the deprecated libs?

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Flutter and Dart plugins, this is my `flutter doctor` output (none of the warnings are relevant):

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.22.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139], locale hu-HU)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0-12.1.pre at C:\Users\fodor\Documents\_Android\FlutterSDK\flutter
    • Framework revision 8b3760638a (7 weeks ago), 2020-09-15 17:47:13 -0700
    • Engine revision 4654fc6cf6
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-110.3.beta)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.50.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Full output:

```yaml
PS C:\Users\fodor\Documents\_Android\Flutter\_FILC4\filcnaplo> flutter build apk --release
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the
APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Note: C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\downloads_path_provider-0.1.0\android\src\main\java\it\nplace\downloadspathprovider\DownloadsPathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-1.13.3\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FileUtils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_cropper-1.3.1\android\src\main\java\vn\hunghd\flutter\plugins\imagecropper\FileUtils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
warning: C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.0\core-lambda-stubs.jar(java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
1 warning
warning: C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.0\core-lambda-stubs.jar(java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
1 warning                                                               
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-1.3.1+2\android\src\main\java\com\tekartik\sqflite\SqflitePlugin.java:1043: warning: [deprecation] Handler() in Handler has been deprecated
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                ^
1 warning
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:9: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
import android.os.AsyncTask;
                 ^
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        ^
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    ^
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:123: warning: [deprecation] doInBackground(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {                 
                        ^
  where Params,Result are type-variables:                               
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                                         ^
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:128: warning: [deprecation] onPostExecute(Result) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value) {
                     ^
  where Result is a type-variable:
C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:131: warning: [deprecation] execute(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    }.execute();
  where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
7 warnings
warning: C:\Users\fodor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.0\core-lambda-stubs.jar(java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning


* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':video_player:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      98,4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you're trying to build apk and it's giving errors? right

Comment: Well yes :D So?

Comment: Try `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`, then build your apk. This may help

Comment: I tried `clean` before, now running `upgrade`...

Comment: @HardikKumar Pretty much the same log. Can't post here, too long.

Comment: The log says `flutter` and `dart` plugins are not installed. Try installing that.

Comment: As I said, I'm using VSCode, and not Android Studio. I don't have to install those plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new SDK version messes with stuff, and I'm posting this answer without being aware of the route cause of the problem. Either way, this should work:

Put this in your `buid.gradle` after the `allprojects{}` section:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || project.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library')) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 29
                buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the output carefully, it says that the (only) error is that there were warnings and because of the compile option -Werror, they're treated as errors. Maybe just remove the -Werror option?

Comment: I'm not directly using the compiler, and can't directly access what commands it's given.